# For loop vs if/else in R

Tags: r, loops

I am struggling to understand why these two bits of code are producing drastically different results:

First some functions:

```
n <- 5000
alpha1 <- rep(NA, n)
Y <- c(replicate(n, sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob=c(1/2, 1/2))))

conditional_sampler <- function(x){      
    sample(c(-1, 1), 1, prob = c(x, 1-x))
  }

 t <- .4

  lower <- function(t){
    runif(1,(.4-t),.4)
  }

  upper <- function(t){
    runif(1,.6,(.6+t))
  }
```

Now the code:

```
alpha1 <- ifelse(Y==1, conditional_sampler(lower(t)), conditional_sampler(upper(t)))
```

vs.

```
 for (i in 1:n){
    if (Y[i]==1) {
      alpha1[i] <- conditional_sampler(lower(t))}
    else {
      alpha1[i] <- conditional_sampler(upper(t))}}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: edited. n can be any number.

Comment: yes, it was initialized.  It seems in the ifelse case I always get either 0 , 5000, or 2470 alpha1==1, which is odd.

Comment: The difference is primarily in (1) performance and (2) random seed. Why is `runif(1)` different from `runif(1)`? Try `set.seed(1)`, then try the `ifelse` code, save its value, then do `set.seed(1)` again and do your `for` code, then compare the vectors. If different, you'll need to be more specific on how they are *"drastically different"*.

Comment: I'm not sure it's this simple. When I run the for loop, the number of 1s in alpha1 varies but hovers around what I expected it to be. In the ifelse, it jumps around between 0, 5000, and 2470, which is nonsensical. I suspect there is some deeper issue I don't understand. I would prefer to use ifelse to significantly reduce run time, but the for loop provides proper results.

Comment: Oh, right ... it's because the "then" and "else" arguments to `ifelse` are returning a single number each (since their input, `t`, is length 1). Since `Y` is a vector, the single-number return value is replicated `length(Y)` times to fill the returned vector.

Comment: I see...do you have any recommendations as to how to speed up the for loop but maintain the alpha1 structure based on the value of Y for each i?

Comment: `sapply(ifelse(Y==1,list(upper),list(lower)), function(f) conditional_sampler(f(t)))` might work for you

Comment: This works but seems to be no faster than the for loop.